# how to find the time in effective way when value get cross the threshold limit

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

There is a graph visualization of list of `(time, count)` value where time in x axis and count in y axis
e.g.

```
 list_1 = [(1, 50000), (2,40000), (3,20000), (4,10000), (5, 5000), (6, 3000), (7,500), (8, 10), (9,100), (10,2000), (11,5000),(11,8000),(12,10000), (13,20000)]
```

My aim is to find the time at which count got increased beyond or equal the `limit = 20000` which is `(13,20000)` along the increase slope side not decrease slope side

[please find the graph for more info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jx5ec.png)

I have written a pseudo code which does the same thing but not in effective way

> But one constraint is the list_1 is not fixed value but is keep on
>   incrementing with new value with f(time, count)

```
def find_limit():
    list_1 = [(1, 50000), (2, 40000), (3, 20000), (4, 10000), (5, 5000), (6, 3000), (7, 500), (8, 10), (9, 100),
              (10, 2000), (11, 5000), (11, 8000), (12, 10000), (13, 20000)]
    found = False
    limit = 20000
    for time, count in list_1:
        if count < limit:
            found = True
        if found:
            if count >= limit:
                return time

print(find_limit())
```

Is there any other way I can get the time when count got increase beyond threshold while the list is keep on updating with new value?

Comment: There are other "times" when the count is less that limit in the data you provided

Comment: Yes, there are the time when count is keep on decreasing upto some point after that again it is start increasing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `numpy`:

```py
import numpy as np

limit = 20000
list_1 = np.array([(1, 50000), (2, 40000), (3, 20000), (4, 10000), (5, 5000), (6, 3000), (7, 500), (8, 10), (9, 100),
              (10, 2000), (11, 5000), (11, 8000), (12, 10000), (13, 20000)])

res=list_1[((list_1[:-1,1]<limit)&(list_1[1:,1]>=limit)).argmax()+1,:]
#list_1[((list_1[:-1,1]<limit)&(list_1[1:,1]>=limit)).argmax()+1,0] in order to get just 13
```

In short:

```py
((list_1[:-1,1]<limit)&(list_1[1:,1]>=limit))
```

Will return Boolean vector with result of comparison of two consecutive numbers for whether `limit` was crossed between them. Left part takes elements from index 0 to one before last, whereas right part takes elements from index 1 till the last, with respective conditions.

Next thing - `argmax()` will return first index where both conditions are met, and we need to add 1, since we want to get index where the line has been crossed, not one before.

Output:

```py
[   13 20000]
```

Comment: My requirement i would like to find the time at which count crossed limit after it went to lowest and all this happens at run time with dynamic value added to list not hardcoded

Comment: You mean values are added to the list in real time and you want to fire alarm whenever ```limit``` is crossed? Unless that is the case, and you have complete, at least temporarily immutable list to work with, my answer should do for you.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC

```
list_1 = [(1, 50000), (2,40000), (3,20000), (4,10000), (5, 5000), (6, 3000), (7,500), 
          (8, 10), (9,100), (10,2000), (11,5000),(11,8000),(12,10000), (13,20000)]

df = pd.DataFrame(list_1, columns=['time', 'count'])

# Set the limit
limit = 20_000
times_over_limit = df[df['count'] < limit]['time'].tolist()

# List of times for which count is less than limit value
times_over_limit
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 11, 12]
```